# Keyboard is disabling

Tags: linux, keyboard, hardware

I stuck with a strange problem on OpenSUSE 13.1, after some random uptime my keyboard is disabling.

I'm not even sure how to concretize this problem, this happening randomly and I can't see any interrelation with other events.

Example: I'm writing a text and then pressing backspace.. and that's it. keyboard is disabled, stuck on infinity backspace press.

Any ideas how I can dig into this problem? (e.g. some hardware failure log or so..?)

Update: I'm using simplest PS/2 keyboard and this never happen on same machine on windows.

Comment: Hardware events are logged in the kernel logs, `/var/log/kern.log` on typical configurations. But defective hardware might not cause a log entry (if the hardware just stops sending events, the OS can't know that it isn't because you've stopped typing). You should try another keyboard. If you press and release the stuck key, does it help?